# css loading spinner not spinning

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

Im trying to recreate this spinner [here](https://kiwicom.github.io/orbit/?path=/story/loading--playground) but I can't seem to figure out why it's not spinning. I'm no good with react so I was thinking this could be achieved through pure css. I've gotten it styled properly but no luck with the spin.

```
<div class="Loading__StyledLoading bWDkpr">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 40 40" class="Loading__StyledSpinner dCPhrt">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="18" type="pageLoader" class="Loading__StyledSpinnerCircle hsiYVK"></circle>
  </svg>
  <div type="pageLoader" class="Loading__StyledLoadingText dpesEv"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.bWDkpr {
  height: 120px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dCPhrt {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: initial;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: initial;
  animation-fill-mode: initial;
  animation-play-state: initial;
  animation-name: cZxgpV;
}

.hsiYVK {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: rgb(186, 199, 213);
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 128px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 64px;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate the `transform` property:

```css
.bWDkpr {
  height: 120px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dCPhrt {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: initial;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: initial;
  animation-fill-mode: initial;
  animation-play-state: initial;
  animation-name: cZxgpV;
}

.hsiYVK {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: rgb(186, 199, 213);
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 128px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 64px;
}

@keyframes cZxgpV {
  from {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Loading__StyledLoading bWDkpr">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 40 40" class="Loading__StyledSpinner dCPhrt">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="18" type="pageLoader" class="Loading__StyledSpinnerCircle hsiYVK"></circle>
  </svg>
  <div type="pageLoader" class="Loading__StyledLoadingText dpesEv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. This helped out. I see what I missed now. Thanks, Daniel!